# Load inline HTML inside QML WebView

Tags: javascript, html, qt, qml

I'd like to load inside a QML WebView some HTML, but I need it to be hard-typed (inline). I can't load an external URL nor a local file.

I can't use this:

```
WebView{
    id:webView
    url:"file:///android_asset/html/index.html";
}
```

And I can't use this:

```
 WebView {
    id: webView

    Component.onCompleted: {

        var resource = 'qrc:/path/to/your/resource.html';
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('GET', resource);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var response = xhr.responseText;
                webView.loadHtml(response);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
}
```

I specifically need to load it for example like this:

```
webView.loadHtml("<p>TEST</p>");
```

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

**loadHtml** works with *inline* **HTML** as long as you also give it a name in the second paramenter, like this:

```
loadHtml("<p>TEST</p>", "index.html")
```